# Not able to install django-filetransfers for python 2.7.18

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am not able to install django-filetransfers for python 2.7.18, I have the same installed in other machine but since I am migrating the project to the new machine I am trying to install it. Please help.

```
pip install django-filetransfers
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-filetransfers (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-filetransfers
```

Comment: [There is no package `django-filetransfers` on PyPI.](https://pypi.org/project/django-filetransfers/) I don't know how you've installed it on your other machine.

Comment: There is no package called ```django-filetransfers```. if you're using a custom package which is hosted on a network, not on a public access then you need to change ```pip.conf``` file. If this is so, then please update the url or host on which I can provide the pip.conf code